# Есть ли разница между Primary key и UNIQ Clustered index?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть ли разница между Primary key и UNIQ Clustered index?

Например, если создать на колонке UNIQ Clustered index, то он не воспринимается студией, как первичный ключ.

Comment: по хорошему ключ это просто объявление, которое реализуется в виде индекса. т.е. индекс для ключа будет построен. Но ключ сам не объявится если будет только индекс. разницы особой нет, правда без объявленного ключа вряд ли получится сделать foreign на него ссылающийся

Comment: Первичный ключ, в дополнение к функциям уникального индекса, несёт функцию однозначной идентификации записи (в первую очередь для подсистемы контроля целостности).

Answer (score 2):

Разница есть. В первую очередь - смысловая - PK - это ключ строки, т.е. значение, прямо указывающее на конкретную строку, тогда как уникальный индекс - это ограничение уникальности определенного набора полей (не обязательно являющихся ключом поля).

Пример: В таблице физ. лиц ФИО и дата рождения могут являться первичным ключом физического лица (хотя не факт, что это правильно, эти данные могут, теоретически, не быть уникальными), а номер паспорта и номер страхового свидетельства могут иметь по уникальному индексу (т.к. не должны повторяться), но не являться первичным ключом.

Кроме того, разница в реализации следующая:

1. по умолчанию PK имеет кластерный индекс, а UI - некластерный
2. UI может иметь NULL-значения, PK - не может.
3. Таблица может иметь только один PK, но неограниченное количество UI.
4. Разница в синтаксисе создания.

Информацию частично взял отсюда, можно ознакомиться с оригиналом: http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/02/difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-key-in-sql-server/